# Pydeck visualization combine column views with joined selecting

Tags: python, pydeck

I want to use Pydeck to visualize locations of interest pulled from OpenStreetMaps using a `ColumnLayer`. I want to draw a radius around each object. I'm currently drawing 2 column layers, one that has a smaller radius and taller height, and one that has a larger radius and smaller height, like so.

```
from OSMPythonTools.nominatim import Nominatim
from OSMPythonTools.overpass import overpassQueryBuilder, Overpass

# Get theaters in region of interest via OpenStreetMap
bbox = [48, 11, 49, 12]
query = overpassQueryBuilder(bbox=bbox, elementType='node', selector='"amenity"="cinema"',out='body')
overpass = Overpass()
result = overpass.query(query)
result_nodes = result.nodes()

import numpy as np
import pydeck as pdk
import pandas as pd

# Format them into a dataframe for visualization
lat = np.array([r.lat() for r in result_nodes])
lon = np.array([r.lon() for r in result_nodes])
id = np.array([r.id() for r in result_nodes])
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon, 'id': id})

view = pdk.data_utils.compute_view(df[['lon', 'lat']])
view.pitch = 40
view.bearing = 10

theaters = pdk.Layer(
    "ColumnLayer",
    data=df,
    get_position=["lon", "lat"],
    get_elevation=5000,
    radius=200,
    get_fill_color=[255, 255, 255, 255],
    pickable=True,
    auto_highlight=True,
)
range = 20000

theaters_range = pdk.Layer(
    "ColumnLayer",
    data=df,
    get_position=["lon", "lat"],
    get_elevation=1000,
    radius=range,
    get_fill_color=[100, 255, 100, 20],
    pickable=True,
    auto_highlight=True,
)
r = pdk.Deck(
    layers=[theaters, theaters_range],
    initial_view_state=view
)

r.to_html()
```

[image]

However, I don't want the green radius circles and white location indicator cylinders to be **independently** selectable. I want it so that when the mouse hovers over a white cylinder, both the white cylinder and the green radius indicator are selector and are highlighted together. They both have the same id, assigned from OpenStreetMaps. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!